# When using Google Analytics for 2 subdomains, how to attribute a conversion to the 'starting' subdomain?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a setup in Google Analytics with 1 property. My website consists of 2 subdomains: www. and blog. Under **Tracking Info** > **Referral Exclusion List**, I have added the topdomain to the list.

I have a view that only shows data from www. There are a number of Goals defined. I'd like to know whether a session leading to a conversion started on either www. or blog. In other words, attribute the conversion to the subdomain where the session started.

Comment: What about adding a goal funnel with the first required step www. or blog. ?

Comment: @marian - I'm afraid that won't work, as it does not necessarily have to be in the same session.